# Receiving POST requests to browser on an event

Tags: php, api, post

I hope somebody can help.

I have created an API that stores a phone number and a callback URL. When somebody rings the stored phone number, this phone number and the phone number of the caller is posted to the callback URL. If i use PostBin, it looks like this:

```
11:23 Jul xx 2011 -- 212.187.206.30 ?from=02070xxxxxx&to=02030xxxxxx
```

My question being, if the user has a browser perminatly open, how can the callback info(Users phone number & Callers phone number) be automaticly be displayed and updated, without the user refreshing the browser to see the calls since the last refresh?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot "post" information to the browser, that isn't how the Internet works. You can periodically send AJAX requests for new information to the server from the browser, or use [long polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling) to approximate "pushing" data from the server to the browser, but there is no mechanism by which the server can initiate a connection to the client and force it to update what it is displaying.

Comment: I hear what your saying, but, what about websites that have live text updates, where the infomation is updated, without the browser refreshing - how does that work????

Comment: @Bifterss The work *exactly* as I say above. They use long polling or periodically fetch the latest updates from the server.